# Is every $\Pi_2$ set the continuous image of a $\Delta_2$ set?

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

Title says it:

Is every $\Pi_2$ set the continuous (surjective) image of a $\Delta_2$ set?
Any book suggestions for questions like these?